# Use jquery to distribute array elements to list randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simulator here that's working just fine, this simulator have 48 blocks (DIV elements), i'm using `Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1)` to randomly attach the results on each block. The problem is that they're too close on the final simulation (see image below):

[image]

Is there a jquery / javascript function where i can return the array items from the simulation odd/even? Like, it will add each block like: `1,3,5,7,9` then `2,4,6,8`.

My code looks like this right now:

```
if(adicionados.length < 48)
            {
                while(i<=eE && adicionados.length < 48)
                {
                    sol = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
                    if(adicionados.length == 0 || adicionados.indexOf(sol) == -1)
                    {                       
                        adicionados.push(sol);
                        //console.log(adicionados);
                        $("#base"+sol).attr("src", foto);
                        $("#base"+sol).attr("data-i", $(this).parent().parent().find('.relacionados-img').attr('data-cor')); 

                        i++;
                    }
                }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain a little more ? You said "The problem is that they're too close on the final simulation". Can you please attach a photo of your desired pattern ? Thank you.

Comment: @InsomniacSabbir, just changed the image with the current and desired pattern. Thanks for your help.

Comment: whan you generate a new number test it if is "near" a existing number ,if it is, generate another one and test until you finish the numbers

Comment: Why are you even using the random function if you want to obtain a regular chessboard pattern?

Comment: Logically it seems like you want random to get the value in the block, not to choose which block to place a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just two for loop because you have fixed row and col number and you are trying to draw a fixed pattern.

```
for(var i=1;i<=8;i++)
{
    for(var j=1;j<=6;j++)
    {
        var sol=(i*6)+j;//if you are naming the boxes from left to right.
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            if(j%2==1)
            {
             //your code to draw those boxes.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(j%==0)
            {
                //your code to draw those boxes.
            }
        }
    }
}
```